# Scatterplot Reference Line (not the trendline) in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, scatter-plot, powerbi-custom-visuals

I'm trying to add a reference line to the scatterplot which is used to understand if the data points are aligned with the line. The problem is I have the reference line data in another table which is connected on the main data. I was able to overlay the line chart I created for the reference line but unable to synchronize the x-axis. I don't know if there is any better approach for this, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

My Data Format with sample data for reference line:

| PRODUCT | QUANTITY | PRICE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 1 | 2.5 |
| ABC | 100 | 2.4 |
| ABC | 1000 | 2.1 |
| BCD | 1 | 1.9 |
| BCD | 500 | 3.7 |
| BCD | 10000 | 2.3 |

So, when I select the PRODUCT on the scatterplot, I get the point of sale records as datapoints. I'm supposed to plot the reference line details so that it forms a curve. The line should be plotted at for product ABC (1,2.5),(100,2.4),(1000,2.1).. Like this

Comment: You could look to create min and max measures that you can then use for both charts to keep their axis in sync.